# Detect datatable date field and force date format in EPPlus export

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

I have a button on my page that when clicked exports data from a gridview to excel.

```
protected void btExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Output.xlsx");

    DataTable dt= gvOutput.DataSource as DataTable;

    ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
    using(pck)
    {
      ExcelWorksheet wsDt = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
      wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, TableStyles.None);
      wsDt.Cells[wsDt.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

      Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());

    }

    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

This is working fine using the above code, however date fields are formatted as integers. I understand specific cells can be forced to have a certain format, but my issue is that the date columns will change as the dataset for the gridview is dynamic.

I need a way to identify on the fly which column is a date and to force the format of that column to be a date time.

I imagine it will involve an IF statement like this but I haven't got a clue what to put in it or where to put it!

```
if (dt.Columns[x].DataType == typeof(DateTime))
{ 
    //do something
}
```

Any ideas/help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Loop through the DataTable columns and determine which ones are DateTime values.  If you find one, then set the format for the column as shown below.  I haven't tested the code, but it should be the general logic to follow.

```
...
wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, TableStyles.None);
int colNumber = 1;

foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) 
{        
    if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
    { 
         wsDt.Column(colNumber).Style.Numberformat.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM";
    }    
    colNumber++;      
}

wsDt.Cells[wsDt.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
```

Comment: Perfect. But "colNumber++" should be outside of the if-statement:

`if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
{ 
    wsDt.Column(colNumber).Style.Numberformat.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM";
} 

colNumber++;`

Comment: @FlorianD.You are correct.  I've edited my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but I believe that @desiguy's and @Rick S's answers are not totally correct.

**In @desiguy's answer**, the statement `colNumber++` is outside the `foreach` loop on the datatable columns.

Therefore, because the index increment is done outside the loop, the loop will always work on `colNumber=1`.

**Regarding to @Rick S's solution**; If I am not mistaken, in the EPPlus, the column indexes begin with 1 and not 0, so , the statement:

```
wsDt.Column(colNumber++).Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
```

should be as follows:

```
wsDt.Column(++colNumber).Style.Numberformat.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
```

while there are **two** differences:

1. The `colNumber++` was changed to `++colNumber`. In that case, the column will start with 1 and not with 0, so you won't get an error
2. The `mm/dd/yyyy` was changed to `MM/dd/yyyy` because the lower case `mm` represents minutes and not months, hence, `MM` is the correct syntax for month representation

Another simpler solution is only setting the `int colNumber = 0;` to `int colNumber = 1;` and you get the same result.

Answer (score 4):

Slight modification to the above answer. Almost correct. I fixed it with below code.

```
wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, TableStyles.None);

int colNumber = 0;
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) 
{
    colNumber++;
    if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
    { 
       wsDt.Column(colNumber).Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
    }          
}

wsDt.Cells[wsDt.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
```

Comment: I suggest You to request edit of the original answer for the next time.

Answer (score 1):

Fully corrected (and tested) code:

```
        int colNumber = 0;

        foreach (DataColumn col in DataToExport.Columns)
        {
            colNumber++;
            if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                wsDt.Column(colNumber).Style.Numberformat.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM";
            }
        }
```

Comment: This code will iterate through the columns of the DataTable, and, for each DataType that is DateTime, it will format the columns in the resulting spreadsheet, so that dates appear in the format selected (ex. "01/05/2005 12:00:00 AM") instead of as a number.